# How do I use Rhino to remove <scripts> tag?

Tags: java, javascript, regex, jsoup, rhino

I have an HTML email message that I parse using Jsoup :-

`Jsoup.parse(bizmsg.getMessageBody()).text()`

But it can't remove script tags :-

```
<script>
document.write("Bazinga!")
</script>
```

I have been using regex like this :-

```
String(v).replace(/(?:<script.*?>)((\n|\r|.)*?)(?:<\/script>)/ig, "");
```

to successfully remove scripts. But I came across this question [JSoup to parse <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993943/jsoup-to-parse-script-tag)

How do I use Rhino to parse scripts ? Code-Sample would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: did this answer helped you out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Rhino to remove  `<script>`  tags. Use simple CSS selectors in JSoup and remove the obtained nodes. Here a minimal example on www.google.com

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://www.google.com"),5000);
    Elements elems = doc.select("script");
    for (Element elem : elems)
        elem.remove();
    System.out.println(doc);

}
```